# Stack will unmount after reboot

Tags: mount, fstab, vps

I have a mounted a partial disk on my Ubuntu VPS.

After a reboot the disk will be unmounted.

I can remount it manually but it keeps unmounting after rebooting the VPS and this stops the `cron` jobs I use for making backups.

In `/etc/fstab` I added the line:

```
https://[mylink].stackstorage.com/remote.php/webdav/ /var/stack davfs user,rw,noauto 0 0
```

`[mylink]` = my own stack storage name.

The url is correct. If I open it then it asks for my credentials and gives back an "Ok" status.

I don't use users on my VPS; I do everything as root (not sure if this could be the issue).

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.transip.nl/vragen/756-stack-externe-voor-mijn-gebruiken/) to set up my partial disk (sorry it's in Dutch).

Answer (score 0):

try to add `_netdev` and remove `noauto` to your `/etc/fstab` entry.
Example:

```
https://[mylink].stackstorage.com/remote.php/webdav/ /var/stack davfs user,_netdev,rw 0 0
```

[From the Manual Page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mount.8.html):

```
_netdev
          The filesystem resides on a device that requires network access (used to prevent
          the system from attempting to mount these filesystems until the network has been
          enabled on the system).


noauto - The filesystem will NOT be automatically mounted at startup, or when mount passed -a. You must explicitly mount the filesystem.
```

More info: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I did change "noauto" to "auto" but it still won't work. Also tried to remove it.